# How to sort a column by a certain keyword/s that is included somewhere in the cells of a column?

Tags: excel

I want to sort a document with over 1500 rows. In column C of the document I have "job tittles", there are many job titles, and many variation of how the job titles are written.  Is there a way I can sort the job titles and bring up those who use certain keywords like "engineer", "technician", "mechanic", on top of the column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate ComboBox from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504328/populate-combobox-from-table)

Comment: Sort & Filter > Custom sort

Comment: The custom sort almost does the job.  How do you a custom sort when the "keyword" that you want to sort is not an stand alone word in the cell?

Comment: Turn filters on for you data   `Data > Filter`     Then under the filter dropdown, select "Text Filters" and then select "Contains"  to filter for all or part of a word

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is entering a True or False formula to see if the cells contain a "keyword", then I sorted the True or False and got the data in the document of those containing the keyword I was looking for.  I had to do the same for each keyword I was searching. I don't think it is the fastest way to do it but it got it done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Custom list`. Go to `Sort & Filter` -> `Custom sort`. In `Order` field choose `Custom list...`. In the `New list` enter desired keywords in desired order. Click `Add`, then `OK`, `OK`.

[image]

Comment: The custom list didn't work for me because the "keywords" that I am looking for are not stand alone keyword. The word "engineer" might be in between other words such as "mechanical engineer", "system engineer", "project engineer", etc...  So, the custom list won't catch all of the cells needed to do the complete sort in the column.

Comment: But this will not work , if our custom list is large enough, say 39 values

Comment: Important is to note the Cases of entered excel cell values, based on upper or lower cases, the sort result vary