# VBA ComboBox define rowsource from a part of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a Userform containing some ComboBoxes. I tried to populate the RowSource from a table named "Work_type".

| Work Type |
| --- |
| Painter |
| Metal worker |
| Bricklayer |
| Window installer |
| Plumber |
| Carpenter |
| Labourer |
| Heavy machine operator |

It is simple if it uses the whole table:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 7
    Controls("ComboBox" & i).RowSource = "Work_type"
Next i
```

Let's say it is a number of ComboxBox for each person choosing their work type separately. However, some people are restricted to some work types in some situations. Then, I only want a part of the table to be their option. How should I extract the data from the table with only a part of it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need the header (a benefit of using `.RowSource`), you will have to copy the relevant data per user to another range and use this range with the relevant combo box. If not (i.e. you could use a label for the header), you could use arrays with `.List` instead. You should share more information and code to receive a useful answer.

Comment: How do you know that restriction? Is it stored somewhere in your Work_type table or somewhere else?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for the keywords of the `arrays with .List`. I found a [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414619/populate-combobox-in-vba-with-array-elements) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504328/populate-combobox-from-table) which introduces the method to convert the table to an array and set `.List` to that array. However, I still don't know how to assign a part of the data from table to the array or recall the array with only part of it. Is it no such thing like `Controls("ComboBox" & I).List = testArray(1 to 20)`?

Comment: @FunThomas The restriction is based on the work experience or certificate per person. At this moment, I haven't made a table to store that info. I just tried to make sure if this kind of method is workable. Is it possible to convert the data from table to combobox and narrow the option when it is needed?